# Windows Server Backup "Reading Data; please wait..."

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, networking, usb-flash-drive, windows-server-backup

On windows Server 2008 R2 I have recently added the windows server backup (WSB) feature.

Opening WSB I get the message "Reading Data; please wait...".  This message fails to go away, even after leaving the server for over 12 hours.  I also notice in the task manager that svchost.exe (username: networkservice) is using all available processing power.  So I terminated that process and then WSB comes on-line.

However after restarting the server and WSB the issue reoccurs.  WSB also fails to recognize my store-in-go flash drive (2gb).

What is the underlying problem here?

Comment: Can you provide more information ? Did you ever setup WSB to do backup ? What about if you remove this flash drive before launching WSB console ? what about event log errors?

Comment: @MathieuChateau, I have never setup WSB to do a backup.  Removing the flash drive has no effect, the problem existed prior to us connecting the flash drive.  The are no errors in the event log.

Comment: Have you tried running a backup with the WBADMIN command line tool to see if it completes successfully? Sometimes the GUI of Windows Server Backup can be the problem, but not the backup program itself.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Windows Server 2008 R2. I was also trying to use Windows Server Backup to mount a recently backed-up vhd. My Windows Server Backup program was also stuck forever at "Reading Data Please Wait." (My vhd was saved to a USB-mounted external drive).

I am not going to answer the question of "What is the underlying problem here?" Because to me the more important questions is, "Is there another (easy) way to achieve my goal? There sure is, and it's built into Windows.

Here's how I achieved my goal.

First, you have to kill off this stuck backup process. Super simple: Just go into SERVICES and restart "Block Level Backup Engine."

Now that we are out of that stuck program, we still need to get into the Windows Server Backup vhd.

I was able to very quickly and easily mount the backup vhd as logical (usable) hard drive by using a built-in Windows program called DISKPART.

Follow These Easy steps:

Open command prompt and just type DISKPART

It returns a few lines indicating that DiskPart is started.

Next type SEL VDISK file=”the-location-of-your-file-including-the-file-name”

For example:

DISKPART> SEL VDISK file="J:\WindowsImageBackup\99-DC02\Backup 2017-01-16 070031\2a7efb56-0b8e-11e4-8d4c-806e6f6e6963.vhd"

It returns: DiskPart successfully selected the virtual disk file.

Now type ATTACH VDISK

It returns: 100 percent completed

After a few secs, your vhd will mount as a new logical drive. You can now dig into this drive with your Windows Explorer GUI just the same as any. I was able to retrieve files that I needed by dragging them to the desktop.

When you are done retrieving files, and you want to quit, go back to your command prompt window and type DETACH VDISK

It returns: DiskPart successfully detached the virtual disk file.

Thank you Microsoft for an Excellent Utility!

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me : Run the backup software as administrator! That is, right click on the icon, and run as Admin. That is all it took to get it to work perfectly.

Additionally, to make the 'Windows Server Backup' program always run as administrator:

1. Locate windows server backup program in the start menu, right click and select properties
2. On the 'windows Server Backup properties' ensure the shortcut tab is selected
3. Click the advanced button
4. On the 'advanced properties' window 'Check' the box 'Run as Administrator' and click ok

   5. On the 'Windows Server Backup Properties' window click OK

Answer (score -2):

Do you have an iSCSI volume mounted?  We mounted a NAS via iSCSI and ever since this is exactly what we see, when it was fine prior with a local partition only.  Good grief!  Even after WSB *FINALLY* Loads, good luck trying to launch the wizard to change a schedule or something.  I wish I could solve this, as it's a major PiTA!

Comment: It is not a constructive answer. If you have questions to OP place them in comments.